# Get Email and Password for AWS Post Confirmation Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, amazon-cognito-triggers

After a user confirms their email, we want to run a Post Confirmation Lambda in AWS.

This lambda will store the user's email and password to a database that is separate from Cognito, so we need to fetch these credentials from AWS.

We believe it should be possible from the `event` object, but we can't find anything about this in the official documentation.

Is it possible to fetch a user's email and password from AWS from within a Post Confirmation Lambda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After inspecting `vars(context)` and `event`, it seems that it is impossible to get a user's password from within the post confirmation lambda itself, as these objects do not contain it.

Thanks to everyone who helped.